# How to unpack format?

Tags: python, struct, udp, unpack, tftp

I'm working with sockets 2 different folders on computers. I'm creating a basic TFTP client/server program. My code is as follows:

```
def RRQ (filename):
    format = "!H%ds" % (len(filename)+1)
    format += "%ds" % (len(mode)+1)
    s = struct.pack(format, 1, filename, "octet")
    return s
```

I have to say that I've copied it from another web if somebody has any other way to do it more simply pls show me.
What I would like to know is once the WRQ or RRQ (both are the same code) is sent how does the server know the format to unpack?

Question: 
You receive the RRQ from client to server then you have to unpack on server to know the filename but how I could know the format on server to unpack?

thank you guys and sorry for my english :)

Comment: Where does `mode` come from?

Comment: See [RFC 2347](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2347) which shows the layout of the data and options in TFTP Read ReQuest and Write ReQuest packets.